# How to install sflphone on mint 18.1 64-bit?

Tags: apt

I have a Linux Mint 18.1 Serena installed and I am trying to install sflphone softphone application on it. But, I couldn't find it on my repository. How to install ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install it on your system by adding ppa:savoirfairelinux/ppa to your Software Sources.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoirfairelinux/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I tried to add this repository, but there is no repository available for xenial. 'This PPA does not support xenial'

Comment: What is the exact error you get when adding the above repository?

Comment: Same error here: `Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support xenial''.`

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

SFLphone is not available for Ubuntu 16.04 since Mai 2015 the new name is `ring`.

[To install `ring` :](https://ring.cx/en/download/gnu-linux)

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://dl.ring.cx/ring-nightly/ubuntu_16.04/ ring main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ring-nightly-main.list"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys A295D773307D25A33AE72F2F64CD5FA175348F84
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ring
```